# Sharing photo using facebook sdk 4.2.0

Tags: android, facebook, share

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Toast.makeText(SharePage.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(SharePage.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bm).setCaption(description).build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
shareDialog.show(content);
```

The below code is run.
If i have facebook app in the mobile, it's share the photo successful.
But if i delete the facebook app, the callbackManager return the error "`Unable to show the provided content via the web or the installed version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14.`"

Comment: Hi Frankie, have you fixed this issue? I have the same issue on some devices and still not fixed. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

You can only show this dialog if you have native facebook app installed in your device. Try the same code in a device in which facebook app is installed it will work.
If you want to make a custom dialog you need to

```
 -Build a custom interface that posts to the Graph API endpoint /me/feed
 -Implement Facebook Login in your app
 -Request the publish_actions permission when people log into your app
```

Here's the code for posting a link to Facebook from your own interface:

```
  ShareApi.share(content, null);
```

Let me know if you need any assistance.
Mark this answer accepted if this helps.

Comment: In the past, we can use WebDialog to share image without native facebook app. After facebook sdk 4.0, we can't do it?

Comment: U can still use web dialog but that is for story posting.. in which link,caption,name,description parameters are there...If you want to use latest method available.follow my instructions above...
Please mark this answer accepted if this helped.. :) and let me know if still u got a prob.

Comment: In new version sdk, Session is not available. How can i use web dialog?

Comment: You can use LoginManager to use a custom buttton for login or use a default login button of Facebook to maintain session.
If still u does not get me.use any old facebook sdk .Pick from any of your old project and use session class..Please mark this answer up :)

Comment: @Hardeep Can you share small code for here. How to create content.